# How to plot multiple lines on same graph using plotly express (XYXY format data)?

Tags: plotly, plotly-express

I have an excel file with multiple columns data in XYXY format [Data.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTkRV.png). How can I use plotly express to plot multiple lines on same graph? For your reference, I achieved this using the Origin software.[Result.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeSIe.png)

**Comments**: (1) different lines with different colors
(2) set the name of each column Y as the name of each line
(3) both x and y axis have Slider Control to adjust the data range

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- start by generating a dataframe of same structure as your sample data
- your plot is really multiple sets of X/Y arrays across columns.  restructure for all sets of X/Y arrays to be rows, with a column that defines the set (name)
- then it's a very simple basic use case of **Plotly Express**
- have also provided another way in **pandas** using `wide_to_long()` to structure dataframe for plotly

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# generte smaple data in required structure
ROWS = 20
COLS = 5
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        f"{c}{n+1}": a if c == "X" else np.power(a, np.linspace(3, 8, ROWS))
        for n, a in enumerate(np.sort(np.random.uniform(1, 2, (COLS, ROWS))))
        for c in "XY"
    }
)

# generate line chart.  key is restructuring dataframe to be long with a column that defines name/color
px.line(
    pd.concat(
        [
            df.loc[:, [f"{c}{n}" for c in "XY"]]
            .pipe(lambda d: d.rename(columns={c: c[0] for c in d.columns}))
            .assign(name=chr(ord("A") + n * 2 - 1))
            for n in range(1, (len(df.columns) // 2) + 1)
        ]
    ),
    x="X",
    y="Y",
    color="name",
).update_layout(margin={"r":800})
```

#### sample data

| X1 | Y1 | X2 | Y2 | X3 | Y3 | X4 | Y4 | X5 | Y5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.05655 | 1.17941 | 1.00106 | 1.00317 | 1.08131 | 1.26432 | 1.02673 | 1.08236 | 1.13674 | 1.46889 |
| 1.12829 | 1.48273 | 1.12435 | 1.4659 | 1.17564 | 1.69557 | 1.05341 | 1.18507 | 1.17995 | 1.71595 |
| 1.23403 | 2.09918 | 1.1806 | 1.79582 | 1.18304 | 1.8089 | 1.11287 | 1.45807 | 1.20479 | 1.92892 |
| 1.25683 | 2.37794 | 1.25303 | 2.35086 | 1.25923 | 2.39525 | 1.11929 | 1.53275 | 1.20527 | 2.02893 |
| 1.26899 | 2.62586 | 1.26441 | 2.58766 | 1.30377 | 2.93 | 1.12895 | 1.63484 | 1.31977 | 3.07846 |
| 1.28209 | 2.92254 | 1.28889 | 2.98997 | 1.34024 | 3.53909 | 1.24893 | 2.60999 | 1.33975 | 3.53352 |
| 1.35852 | 4.06724 | 1.37546 | 4.30467 | 1.35213 | 3.9804 | 1.27209 | 3.01014 | 1.35568 | 4.02851 |
| 1.40013 | 5.10234 | 1.45365 | 6.11857 | 1.36741 | 4.55027 | 1.27662 | 3.26259 | 1.35574 | 4.36531 |
| 1.45668 | 6.82368 | 1.48403 | 7.5034 | 1.43853 | 6.40061 | 1.37053 | 4.99873 | 1.36458 | 4.88892 |
| 1.53722 | 10.0571 | 1.50537 | 8.98814 | 1.58023 | 11.6633 | 1.39912 | 6.0676 | 1.38998 | 5.85774 |
| 1.54932 | 11.7704 | 1.5474 | 11.6885 | 1.65089 | 16.8308 | 1.4697 | 8.74519 | 1.44385 | 7.91331 |
| 1.55716 | 13.6067 | 1.5512 | 13.3024 | 1.70078 | 22.8881 | 1.52104 | 11.8486 | 1.46135 | 9.358 |
| 1.61261 | 18.9648 | 1.62567 | 19.9306 | 1.71918 | 28.1241 | 1.54101 | 14.3378 | 1.50292 | 12.29 |
| 1.65226 | 25.1355 | 1.70023 | 30.207 | 1.78133 | 40.7424 | 1.55464 | 17.0006 | 1.61183 | 21.4393 |
| 1.68557 | 32.7817 | 1.72353 | 38.0429 | 1.78985 | 48.9649 | 1.58977 | 22.1695 | 1.67353 | 31.2474 |
| 1.80329 | 60.1153 | 1.76449 | 51.6846 | 1.79787 | 58.8716 | 1.61254 | 27.6471 | 1.68959 | 38.2362 |
| 1.88719 | 97.4484 | 1.88748 | 97.5572 | 1.83715 | 80.2828 | 1.76924 | 61.1892 | 1.78649 | 65.6223 |
| 1.9383 | 140.635 | 1.90963 | 125.812 | 1.87891 | 111.451 | 1.77838 | 73.8938 | 1.826 | 90.0264 |
| 1.96985 | 189.662 | 1.92214 | 156.894 | 1.87996 | 132.145 | 1.8462 | 114.857 | 1.8351 | 109.622 |
| 1.99305 | 248.972 | 1.94302 | 203.147 | 1.88243 | 157.67 | 1.87284 | 151.36 | 1.95582 | 214.111 |

#### plot

[image]

#### `wide_to_long()`

```
px.line(
    pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=["X", "Y"], i="index", j="name")
    .reset_index()
    .assign(name=lambda d: d["name"].apply(lambda n: chr(ord("A") + n * 2 - 1))),
    x="X",
    y="Y",
    color="name",
).update_layout(margin={"r": 800})
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help! This reminds me of the demo dataset in the official document of plotly. The most important part of my project is to reconstruct the dataframe and add a label column for each XY column.